# Autorization dialog box always appear when open file from GDrive

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth

i've developped a webapps that use google drive api (javascript) to open file and it can be use directly from google drive to open specific files.
When users open files from Google Drive, an autorization dialog box appear to allow my apps to open the file, but when you re open the same file or another, this dialog box appear too, how can i do to open this dialog box just the first time a user open a file ?

Answer (score 0):

Users do not have to grant access to the app every time they run it. You can store their credentials in a database and reuse them when needed.

Here's an example for Java(You can find more details for other language-specific sample) DrEdit guide for a complete sample app showing how to get a complete set of credentials for every request:

https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/java